# Problems producing different scales per plot with facet_grid_sc

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, facet

I need some help with producing different scales per faceted plot, for anybody who is familiar with `facet_grid_sc`. I have followed the example provided here: https://github.com/zeehio/facetscales, but unfortunately I haven't been able to replicate the result on my own data.

Here is a quick look a the dataset that I'm using:

```
            Date Germany.Yield Italy.Yield Greece.Yield                measure value
    1 2020-04-19        -0.472       1.820        2.287 Italy_v_Germany.Spread 2.292
    2 2020-04-12        -0.472       1.790        2.112 Italy_v_Germany.Spread 2.262
    3 2020-04-05        -0.345       1.599        1.829 Italy_v_Germany.Spread 1.944
 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
 1381 2007-02-11         4.048       4.267        4.302 Greece_v_Germany.Spread 0.254
 1382 2007-02-04         4.049       4.243        4.343 Greece_v_Germany.Spread 0.294
 1383 2007-01-28         4.094       4.303        4.325 Greece_v_Germany.Spread 0.231
```

The following code yields the error: "Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only". I have absolutely no idea what is causing this error, as it seems to me as if I have implemented the `facet_grid_sc` correctly.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(extrafont)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(facetscales)

work_dir <- "D:\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Economic Data\\Historical Yields\\Eurozone"
setwd(work_dir)

germany_yields <- read.csv(file = "Germany 10-Year Yield Weekly (2007-2020).csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
germany_yields <- germany_yields[, -(3:6)]
colnames(germany_yields)[1] <- "Date"
colnames(germany_yields)[2] <- "Germany.Yield"

italy_yields <- read.csv(file = "Italy 10-Year Yield Weekly (2007-2020).csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
italy_yields <- italy_yields[, -(3:6)]
colnames(italy_yields)[1] <- "Date"
colnames(italy_yields)[2] <- "Italy.Yield"

greece_yields <- read.csv(file = "Greece 10-Year Yield Weekly (2007-2020).csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
greece_yields <- greece_yields[, -(3:6)]
colnames(greece_yields)[1] <- "Date"
colnames(greece_yields)[2] <- "Greece.Yield"

combined <- merge(merge(germany_yields, italy_yields, by = "Date", sort = F), 
                  greece_yields, by = "Date", sort = F)

combined <- na.omit(combined)
combined$Date <- as.Date(combined$Date,format = "%B %d, %Y")
combined["Italy_v_Germany.Spread"] <- combined$Italy.Yield - combined$Germany.Yield
combined["Greece_v_Germany.Spread"] <- combined$Greece.Yield - combined$Germany.Yield

fl_dates <- c(tail(combined$Date, n=1), head(combined$Date, n=1))

longcombined <- gather(combined, 
                       key="measure", 
                       value="value", 
                       c("Italy_v_Germany.Spread",
                         "Greece_v_Germany.Spread"))

scales_y <- list(Italy_v_Germany.Spread = scale_y_continuous(),
                 Greece_v_Germany.Spread = scale_y_continuous())

ggplot(data=longcombined, aes(x = Date, y = value)) + geom_line() +

       facet_grid_sc(rows = vars(measure), scales = list(y = scales_y)) +

       geom_blank(aes(y = 0)) +

       scale_x_date(limits = fl_dates,
                    breaks = seq(as.Date("2008-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-01"), by="2 years"),
                    expand = c(0, 0),
                    date_labels = "%Y")
```

If you want to reproduce the example, here are the CSV files that I'm using: https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AEeTM7phVBNGI5c&id=ACB3DC15E10D8AF1%213433&cid=ACB3DC15E10D8AF.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I'm a bit familiar, I [PR](https://github.com/zeehio/facetscales/pull/9)'ed the bit of code that allowed scale transformations.
The issue lies with the date column, as discussed [here](https://github.com/zeehio/facetscales/issues/13). Briefly, `scales::date_trans` is the default transformer for date positions. The thing this transformer does, that many others (e.g. `scales::log10_trans()`) don't, is that it converts the class between date and numeric.

In terms of a fix, I think it might be possible but I don't know a lot about date classes. I'll have a go at it at some point.

Comment: Thank you @teunbrand. The thing is that if I remove the `facet_grid_sc` and replace it with `facet_wrap(~measure, scales = "free_y")`, it works fine; no errors. Only issue from my perspective is that the data stretch beyond the top tick label on the y-axis. That's why I want to configure different scales for either plot so that I can make sure this doesn't happen.

Comment: Yeah it is not an error in ggplot, it is a bug in the facetscales package. I'll give an attempt at fixing it in the next few days.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've submitted a fix https://github.com/zeehio/facetscales/pull/20